# LinkButton not firing on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a good candidate for the ["Works on My Machine Certification Program"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000818.html).

I have the following code for a LinkButton...

```
<cc1:PopupDialog ID="pdFamilyPrompt" runat="server" CloseLink="false" Display="true">
  <p>Do you wish to upgrade?</p>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hlYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="button"></asp:HyperLink>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnNo" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="button"></asp:LinkButton>
</cc1:PopupDialog>
```

It uses a custom control that simply adds code before and after the content to format it as a popup dialog. The **Yes** button is a HyperLink because it executes javascript to hide the dialog and show a different one. The **No** button is a LinkButton because it needs to PostBack to process this value.

I do not have an onClick event registered with the LinkButton because I simply check if IsPostBack is true. When executed locally, the PostBack works fine and all goes well. When published to our Development server, the **No** button does nothing when clicked on. I am using the same browser when testing locally versus on the development server.

My initial thought is that perhaps a Validator is preventing the PostBack from firing. I do use a couple of Validators on another section of the page, but they are all assigned to a specific Validation Group which the **No** LinkButton is not assigned to. However the problem is why it would work locally on not on the development server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the html that is emitted on production and make sure that it has the __doPostback() and that there are no global methods watching click and canceling the event.  Other than that if you think it could be related to validation you could try adding CausesValidation or whatever to false and see if that helps.  Otherwise a "works on my machine" error is kind of hard to debug without being present and knowing the configurations of DEV vs PROD.

Comment: This corrected the problem. I know "Works on my Machine" problems are head to duplicate. Any theories as to what differences between my local and development server would cause this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I created a form with an updatePanel, in the form were some linkbuttons that would open a modalpopup Ajax extender. They worked fine until I added authentication to the site. After that they didn't do anything at all.

Reading your solution I found that some of the linkbuttons WERE working, they were the ones that had CausesValidation explicity set (I only put it in for the ones where I would make that true). Adding CausesValidation="false" to all the other linkbuttons allowed them to work correctly after I was authenticated.

Thanks for your comments everyone, it saved my day!

Comment: Worked for me!!

Comment: I am having the same problem after adding ADFS authentication to my site. Everything worked perfectly when I was using Windows auth, but now I can't get past the first page because the Link Button won't fire on the server. Still works locally though. Adding `CausesValidation="false"` doesn't help though.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of ValidationGroup is that a button with no group specified would trigger all validators on the page.  Have you tried giving the LinkButton a different ValidationGroup?