# LinkButtons not working in ASP.net/C# app production deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I'm running into a situation where link buttons are not responding on a gridview control in one of my apps deployed on a production machine.  Not sure exactly what's going on.

The problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96837/linkbutton-not-firing-on-production-server) although I've examined the output html on the page and it looks reasonable.  Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not nearly enough information for someone to try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with SQL server authentication.  It was not immediately apparent to me because I was running my app in Firefox which did not display any errors; just non responsive UI elements.  Running things in IE revealed the problem.  I adjusted permissions on the database I was trying to connect to and things now work correctly.  Thanks for your suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If these LinkButtons are being dynamically created as part of the DataBinding of the gridview, they must also be re-created during the postback.

Page_load fires before the linkbutton click event does, and if after page_load is complete that same link button has not been re-created there is no event hooked up as the link button does not exist at that time, and the click event won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance javascript is disabled in the browser? I've also had trouble like this with certain AV security apps that muck with javascript in the browser.