# LinkButton OnClick working on local IIS but not on remote server

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, webforms

On a page I have `DropDownList` and a `LinkButton` with the following code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton1" OnClick="FormSubmit" Text="CLICK ME" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void FormSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/location.aspx?dropDownValue=" + this.dropDownList.SelectedValue);
}
```

The purpose of which is for the user to select a value from the drop down list and be forwarded to a new page with a query string relating to that value.

On my local IIS this works find and redirects to *localhost/location.aspx* with the appropriate query string, however, on the remote server all that happens is that the page refreshes.

We've recently had a server outage and some settings on the server (e.g. firewall) have changed which may have thrown this out, but I cannot confirm for definite whether this is a problem that existed before.

So the question is: **what would cause this difference in behaviour between my local IIS and the remote IIS?**

---

Some more details:

Both are IIS 7 running .NETv2

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/13498195/1185053 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953651/1185053

Comment: just guess, have you tried without slash - i mean "location.aspx..." ?

Comment: On the remote server, is `location.aspx` in the root of the website?  Also, what are the actual requests/responses happening?  Use something like Firebug to see what they are (what's being posted, if there's a redirect response, etc.).  It also might be a good idea to put some sort of logging statement in `FormSubmit` to make sure it's being called at all.

Comment: Have you had a look in your browser-of-choice development tools to see which assets are requested? In Chrome Tools, you can check the Network tab to see the requests that are made when you click the link

Comment: @pawlakppp, David: The path is pointing to the correct location - even if it weren't - I'd just get a 404, not the page refreshing.

Comment: @levelnis I'll have a look and report back.

Comment: @levelnis Doing the above confirms that it is just refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ViewState`. I observed the same thing recently. I had code with a link in a `GridView` which was working, but after merging with master pages I couldn't execute `LinkButton` server code. It had lost binding.

There is another case. My Visual Studio behaves weirdly sometimes. After I double click in design view it creates another event as `linkbutton1_click` in code behind.

So after activating `ViewState' / double clicking the linkbutton once I was able to bind the code behind event properly.

Hope it helps.